# Creating variable with the name from user

Tags: unity, c#

I'm not sure this is possible or not but I need to create a variable and set its name to whatever the user wants. Is this doable in C#?

something like this is what I want:

```cs
public string UserInput;
void Start
{
    int "whatever UserInput is" = 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to accomplish by giving the user control over your variable names? You can't do literally what you've asked, but I'm willing to bet there are ways to accomplish your actual goal - you just need to tell us what that is.

Comment: It is not possible to do that. But there are other structures that could resolve your problem, look into Dictionary  https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/lists-and-dictionaries#

Comment: @DMGregory The reason I'm willing to do this is because of `JsonUtilities`. As I have read, the variables' names in the c# file should match the ones in the JSON file. My JSON contains a few lists and users can add more to it so I would like to create a variable that has the same name as the user list's key

Comment: So is your real question "How can I use JsonUtility to deserialize lists of named items?" If so, ask that specifically. [Yesterday's Q&A seems to cover that use case](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/199763/39518) — what behaviour do you need that would differ from this?

Comment: Thanks, everyone, I appreciate your answers and the links.  The problem has been solved, I figured creating different JSON files instead of one file with several lists is much more efficient for what I want. Right now, I have a problem with reading a JSON file, and here's the link of my question for those who are interested:  https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/199781/jsonutility-recognizes-data-but-sets-them-to-null

Answer (score 2):

You do not need this type of functionality. User can set string to any value and you can use the string value to access the variable for example.

```
Dictionary<string,int> dict = new Dictionary< string,int>();
dict.add(userInput, 0);
```