# JsonUtility deserializes list of strings, but all strings come out empty

Tags: unity, c#, json

## What I have

### JSON file

```json
{
  "Story": [
    {
      "Name": "JsonTest",
      "Content": [
        "Sample",
        "Sample2",
        "Sample3",
        "Sample4",
        "Sample5",
        "Sample6",
        "Sample7"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Name": "Jasper_First",
      "Content": [
        "sample",
        "sample2"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Name": "BlackSmith_Sword",
      "Content": [
        "sample",
        "sample2"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "Quest1": [
    {
      "Name": "FirstEncounter",
      "Content": [
        "sample",
        "sample2"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Name": "QuestDetail",
      "Content": [
        "sample",
        "sample2"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

### C# classes

```cs
[System.Serializable]
public class JsonListMember
{
    public string Name;
    public List<string> Content;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Root
{
    public List<JsonListMember> Story;
    public List<JsonListMember> Quest1;
}
```

### Accessing the JSON data

```cs
    private string Texts;

    private void Start()
    {
        Texts = Resources.Load<TextAsset>("Texts/Test").text;
        Root JsonData = JsonUtility.FromJson<Root>(Texts);
        foreach (var item in JsonData.Story)
        {
            print(item.Name + " : {" + string.Join(",", item.Content) + "}");
        }
    }
```

### and here's the result:

[image: Result in Console]

So as you can see the code can read the JSON data and correctly shows the `Name`s but the same can't be said about `Content`. The console shows that the program knows how many texts are in each `Content` but they are all empty strings(`""`) and I've no idea why this is happening.

Comment: You say they are both null and the empty string, but the empty string is not null — these are two completely different values a string can hold. Can you edit your question to clarify whether you're actually getting the value `null` and not `""`?

Comment: I thought they are the same thing. Thanks for notifying me! I've edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was neither the code nor the JSON file. As it turned out, the program I was using for writing the JSON file had some issues for saving, and by solving that the program is working fine. Use the code if it helps you, cheers!