# Creating Dictionary from JSON file

Tags: c#

```cs
[System.Serializable]
public class JsonList
{
    public string Name;
    public List<string> Content;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Root
{
    public List<JsonList> Story;
    public List<JsonList> Quest1;

    Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<string>>> _contentLookup;

    public Dictionary<string, List<string>> this[string name]
    {
        get
        {
            return GetContent(name);
        }
    }

    public Dictionary<string, List<string>> GetContent(string name)
    {
        return _contentLookup[name];
    }

    public void CreateDic()
    {
        _contentLookup = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<string>>> { };
        foreach (var item in Story)
        {
            if (!_contentLookup.ContainsKey(nameof(Story)))
                _contentLookup.Add(nameof(Story), new Dictionary<string, List<string>> { });

            _contentLookup[nameof(Story)].Add(item.Name, item.Content);
        }
    }
}
```

Let's say I have `Root a;`, so I would access different `List<string>`s like this: `a["Story"]["Cave_start"]` (assume I've called `a.CreateDic()` and all of the keys such as "Story" exist)

The problem is that it's not efficient. if I want to access `Quest1` then I have to manually add

```cs
foreach (var item in Quest1)
        {
            if (!_contentLookup.ContainsKey(nameof(Quest1)))
                _contentLookup.Add(nameof(Quest1), new Dictionary<string, List<string>> { });

            _contentLookup[nameof(Quest1)].Add(item.Name, item.Content);
        }
```

in `CreateDic()`

Obviously, this is nothing I would desire to do for Quest2, Quest3, HiddenLevel1, etc. in `Root`.

Any idea how to make it better?

Comment: [I showed you a solution for this yesterday](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/199763/39518), where you only have to write the dictionary code once.

Comment: @DMGregory Yes, and thanks to you I wrote this code. But the thing is that I want to have a dictionary of all of the `_contentLookup`s (in your example) and use it like this: `MainDic["Story"]["Cave_Start"]` but in your example, it would be `MainDic.Story["Cave_Start"]`

Comment: A short notice: I've completely changed the code in the question according to a deleted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was a grave mistake in the JSON file, the structure I used was this:

```json
{
  "Story":
  [
    {"Name":"FirstEncounter", "Content":[
      "sample",
      "sample2"
    ]},
    {"Name":"LaGrandDuel", "Content":[
      "sample",
      "sample2"
    ]}
  ],
  "Quest1":
  [
    {"Name":"FirstEncounter", "Content":[
      "sample",
      "sample2"
    ]},
    {"Name":"QuestDetail", "Content":[
      "sample",
      "sample2"
    ]}
  ]
}
```

The problem is that I use `Story` and `Quest1` as **Keys**, not **Values**!

and so I changed the structure to this:

```json
{
  "Main": [
    {
      "FamilyName": "Story",
      "Divisions": [
        {
          "Name": "JsonTest",
          "Content": [
            "sample",
            "sample2"
          ]
        },
        {
          "Name": "Jasper_First",
          "Content": [
            "sample",
            "sample2"
          ]
        },
        {
          "Name": "BlackSmith_Sword",
          "Content": [
            "sample",
            "sample2"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "FamilyName": "Quest1",
      "Divisions": [
        {
          "Name": "FirstEncounter",
          "Content": [
            "sample",
            "sample2"
          ]
        },
        {
          "Name": "QuestDetail",
          "Content": [
            "sample",
            "sample2"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And by doing this you will get rid of writing a new part of code for each `Quest2`, Quest3`, etc.